# How To Read Text File to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, file-io, datagridview

I've a project that I want to load text file to a `DataGridview`.
Data :

```
"#Tools Must You Have  
Tool_1 Screwdriver T1    
Tool_2 Screw T2   
Tool_3 Ruler T3"
```

I have two button(`btSave` & `btOpen`) and a `DataGridview` has two columns(`Tools` & `Name`)
i want to read the data to `DataGridview`, but I want skipping the line beginning with "`#`"

I tried it with this code

```
Private Sub LoadGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
    ThisGrid.Rows.Clear()
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    Using objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Filename)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, " ")
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub
```

This code is wrong, when it's loaded, text in column is not same, only read one word "`Screwdriver`" not "`screwdriver T1`",
any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run that split function, you're splitting the entire string on each space so you end up with 3-long array and the T1 is in the third string. I'm assuming your table is defined with two columns only. Try this:

```
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        If Textline.Trim.Length > 0 AndAlso not TextLine.StartsWith("#") Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(TextLine.Split(" ")(0), textLine.Replace(TextLine.Split(" ")(0), "").Substring(1))
        End If
    Loop
```

And really, I'm making all kinds of assumptions about your assignment and your data, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: it's error "String cannot be of zero length." is happening when i load the data, "#Tools Must You Have", firstly i want to ignore that text.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the error. Put a breakpoint on the line that adds the line to the grid and see what TextLine equals at that point. Also, see the above change to filter out the first row of your data. (ETA: I added the length filter in case there's a blank line at the start or end of the data that's actually causing the reported error.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub LoadGridData(ByVal ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
    ThisGrid.Rows.Clear()
    ThisGrid.Rows.AddRange( 
        File.ReadLines(FileName).
              Where(Function(line) Not line.TrimStart().StartsWith("#")).
              Select(Function(line) line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), 2)).
              ToArray() 
     ) 
End Sub
```

Note (among other things) the change from `ByRef` to `ByVal`. It's easy to miss that one, and `ByRef` vs `ByVal` probably doesn't mean what you think it does. Remember that `ByVal` in VB.Net *still passes references*. The difference is that it makes a *copy* of the reference value, but since that copy still refers to the same DataGridView object, it will do what you want it to do. The only time you should use `ByRef` is if you need to make an assignment directly to the variable, and you want that assignment to show up in the calling code. This is different from assigning to a property of the object. You only need this if you want to actually replace the entire object, and that should be almost never.